# Mongoose Model Population

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm struggling with Mongoose model population to reference data from two MongoDB collections.  The two schemas are as follows:

```
// SCHEMA SETUP - Artist
var artistSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  venuesPlayed: {
      id: {
         type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
         ref: "Venue"     
      }
  }

});

var Artist = mongoose.model("Artist", artistSchema);


// SCHEMA SETUP - Venue
var venueSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   name: String,
   address: String,
});

var Venue = mongoose.model("Venue", venueSchema);
```

What I am trying to do is on the showArtist.ejs (which lists details about a specific artist), I want the user to be able to select from a dropdown list of all venues, and select the venues that the artist has played at.  So the two points I am struggling with and would greatly appreciate assistance with are:

1. Is the way I have referenced the Venue schema under the Artist Schema correct?
2. On the showArtist.ejs page, how to reference the venues in a dropdown (e.g. html select tag or something similar) list?  It is this point in particular I'm having difficultly with as everything I've tried I'm getting an error, 'venues in undefined'.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your first point, your schemas are mostly correct, however if you want to store multiple venue references within your artist schema, you probably want to use a list instead:

```
var artistSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    venuesPlayed: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Venue"     
    }]
});
```

This will allow you to retrieve the ObjectIds for every venue by referencing `venuesPlayed[index]`, no need to assign extra keys unless you want to store additional attributes.

For your second point, you can use the [`populate()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) method to replace the ObjectIds with the referenced document(s) on retrieval:

```
let artist = await Artist.findOne(some_query).populate({ 'venuesPlayed' });
```

In this case, `some_query` would be a [`JSON query`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html) to uniquely identify a specific artist. If left blank, Mongoose would simply return the first artist document it found within the database. Alternatively, you could use [`findById()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findById) if you have retained the ObjectId as reference.

In absence of the `populate()` method (e.g. Mongoose < 3.2) your alternative would be to use a [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) aggregation, or manually iterate over the venue ObjectIds in a separate query.

If you are performing this query server-side (as is often the case), you would still need to send this data client-side. With [Express](https://expressjs.com/), you could achieve this by [creating a route](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html) and either using [`res.send()`](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.send), or more likely in your case [`res.render()`](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.render). You can find a full API reference in the links provided, but a simple (static) route might look something like this:

```
app.get('/showSomeArtist', function(req, res) {
    let artist = await Artist.findOne({ name: 'Some Artist' }).populate({ 'venuesPlayed' });
    res.render('showArtist', { artist });
}
```

You can then access the `artist` object from your EJS file. You would need to elaborate on the example above to change which artist is rendered. I would suggest looking into route parameters as a potential solution (in the Express documentation).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Though I'm still struggling on the second point; I have tried using this code on the showArtist.ejs tab:     `<% let artist = await Artist.findOne('name', 1).populate({ 'venuesPlayed' }); %>` But I am getting this error: SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier in /home/ubuntu/workspace/IntroToCommandLine/views/showArtist.ejs while compiling ejs.  Apologies but I'm not really clear where I should be putting this line given my inexperience, and what I should be putting in the brackets where you reference 'show_query'.  Any advice please?

Comment: @Martin I have updated my answer to reflect your inquires